# Can I enable 'more' by default in cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

It may seem like an insane convenience, but, if there's a way to run ANY cmd command with `| more` by default, please let me know (also let me know if there's an obvious downside to this that I'm not seeing)

If another command follows, output should be suppressed partially (max 1x page of `more` or entirely).

Comment: Short answer: No. Unless you alias every possible command.

Comment: if you think it's more than an opinion, please post it as answer so I could mark it as possible 'solution' (i.e. there is none)

Comment: You can scroll up. In Command Prompt properties you can set the actual window size and the scroll buffer. Set the scroll buffer to 9999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a way to run ANY `cmd` command with `| more` by default?

No. Not unless you do something like alias every command, using for example [Doskey - recall commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html).

Doing this would potentially break a lot of batch files ...